# Issue sending big string over TCP

Tags: vb.net, tcpclient

I have the following function to send and receive data it works OK for short strings like 150 bytes, but with a string of 2500 bytes it get stuck.
I tried to send some data with HTWin and nothing get the other end of the net.
So receiver on the other end never get even a character.
I tried also with the old Hyperterminal with same result.

```
Private Function SendReport(ByVal Msg As String, ByVal Host As String, ByVal Port As String) As String
   Try
       Dim Tx As New TcpClient()

       Dim stream As NetworkStream = Nothing
       Dim CloseStream As Boolean = False
       Dim LingerMode As New LingerOption(True, 5)

       ' String to store the response ASCII representation.
       Dim responseData As [String] = [String].Empty

       Tx.NoDelay = True
       Tx.LingerState = LingerMode
       Tx.SendTimeout = 10000
       Tx.ReceiveTimeout = 10000
       Tx.Connect(Host, Port)

' Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array.
       Dim data As [Byte]() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Msg)

       ' Get a client stream for reading and writing.
       '  Stream stream = client.GetStream();
       stream = Tx.GetStream()
       CloseStream = True
       'stream.WriteTimeout = 100
       ' Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
       stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)

       'Tx.Connected 
       ' Receive the TcpServer.response.
       ' Buffer to store the response bytes.
       data = New [Byte](256) {}


       ' Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
       Dim bytes As Int32 = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length)
       responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes)

       If CloseStream = True Then
           stream.Close()
       End If
       Tx.Close()

       Return responseData
   Catch ex As Exception
       WriteRTBLog(ex.Message, Color.Red)
       WriteRTBLog(ex.StackTrace, Color.DarkRed)
       Return "Error"
   End Try

End Function
```

If I split the big string into smaller one and call this function over and over all the data reach the other end.

Also, I need to get an ACK packet that is big too and the code must wait for and special character that indicates the end.
I was thinking in to create a Thread with a TcpListener but, Is possible to have a TcpListener in the same port of a TcpClient?

The whole idea is to send a big string that is separated by an special character and finished with another special character.

The other end receive the data, split the string using the first special character and send one ACK by every item in the split function.
And in the last ACK send the second special character to indicate the end of the communication, so my application can process the received data properly.

I think I'm drowning in a glass of water.

Comment: Have you looked at the specifications for other protocols that do this? Have you written a specification for the way you've chosen to do it? It's worth the effort to do so. Look at the specification for SMTP, for example, because it does this kind of thing.

Comment: Ok, I will search an specification sheet. Thanks